# 2 set of android API since last R10 update

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed the new r10 tools and now when I create a new project, I have 2 choices for each API level.

Example: for API level 8 I have the following choices:

Taget: Android 2.2 Vendor: Android Open Source Project Platform: 2.2 API level: 8

Taget: Google APIs Vendor: Google Inc. Platform: 2.2 API level: 8

any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It looks like the Google Inc add-ons got installed.
I simply uninstaled them.

Here is a related question:

What are those Google add-ons ???

Comment: Not sure what else it's used for, but it includes the MapView and related apis.